# How to merge AND & OR together

Tags: regex

[You can check the regex101 page from here.](https://regex101.com/r/2L613R/1)

I have a list of adresses in different formats and non-english. Assume my list is like below.

```
KENNEDY CAD. SİRKECİ ARABALI VAPUR İSKELESİ FATİH/ İSTANBUL
YAVUZTÜRK MAH. KARADENİZ CAD. NO:2 ÜSKÜDAR/ İSTANBUL
HAMİDİYE MAH. ALPEREN SOK. NO:15/2  ÇEKMEKÖY/ İSTANBUL
UĞUR MUMCU MAH. YUNUS EMRE CAD. NO:25 KARTAL/ İSTANBUL
```

The regex I've written is as following:

`(?:(?:\p{L}* M[Aa]?[Hh][. ])? *|(?:\p{L}* C[Aa]?[Dd][. ])? *)`

My regex return each character as match, but i need to get 4 matches which are:

```
KENNEDY CAD.
YAVUZTÜRK MAH. KARADENİZ CAD. 
HAMİDİYE MAH. 
UĞUR MUMCU MAH. YUNUS EMRE CAD.
```

How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tET1fr/3)):

```
^(?=.*C[Aa][Dd]\s*\.).*?C[Aa][Dd]\.|^.*?M[Aa][Hh]\s*\.
```

---

This will match all string until `CAD.` or if not found until `MAH.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)*\s+(?:M[Aa]?[Hh]|C[Aa]?[Dd])\.?(?:\s+\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)*\s+(?:M[Aa]?[Hh]|C[Aa]?[Dd]))*\.?
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)*` - a word and then zero or more whitespace separated words
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?:M[Aa]?[Hh]|C[Aa]?[Dd])` - `M`, an optional `A` or `a` and then `h` or `H`, or `C`, an optional `A` or `a` and then `D` or `d`
- `\.?` - an optional dot
- `(?:\s+\p{L}+(?:\s+\p{L}+)*\s+(?:M[Aa]?[Hh]|C[Aa]?[Dd]))*` - zero or more sequences of one or more whitespaces and the pattern described above
- `\.?` - an optional dot

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AldxfS/2). Or, a bit less precise and efficient, but shorter:

```
^(?:\s*[\p{L}\s]+(?:M[Aa]?[Hh]|C[Aa]?[Dd])\.?)+
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AldxfS/3). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\s*[\p{L}\s]+(?:M[Aa]?[Hh]|C[Aa]?[Dd])\.?)+`  - one or more sequences of

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `[\p{L}\s]+` - one or more letters or whitespaces
  - `(?:M[Aa]?[Hh]|C[Aa]?[Dd])` - `M`, an optional `A` or `a` and then `h` or `H`, or `C`, an optional `A` or `a` and then `D` or `d`
  - `\.?` - an optional dot

Comment: But if the adress is in a text, then the regex is returning the whole text from the beginning of the string.

Comment: @grey No idea what you mean, if you want to say the lines are just a piece of a larger text, you can probably add `(?m)` at the start, `(?m)^(?:\s*[\p{L}\s]+(?:M[Aa]?[Hh]|C[Aa]?[Dd])\.?)+`

Comment: Assume I have this text: `my current adress is YAVUZTÜRK MAH. KARADENİZ CAD. NO:25 KARTAL/ İSTANBUL` then what your regex is matching is that `my current adress is YAVUZTÜRK MAH. KARADENİZ CAD. ` but it is only supposed to match with `YAVUZTÜRK MAH. KARADENİZ CAD. `

Comment: @grey And then my question is WHY? Your pattern requirements must be part of the question, you should not only come up with this when an answer is already given to your current question.

Comment: Because this work is basically for retrivial of adresses from data. And the adresses are in different formats. And the work needs to be done using pure Regex. The aim here is not the getting all of the adresses in the correct format but with the highest accuracy possible.

Comment: @grey So, how can you describe the beginning of an address? Address if free text, regex is regular language. What regularity is there for address start? If you cannot formulate this, there is no solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249188/discussion-between-grey-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: @grey Does https://regex101.com/r/tqd31B/2 help?